# Create custom reporter for Catch2 in single header version

Tags: c++, catch2

There is already a section in Catch2 documentation about [how to create custom reporters](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/reporters.md). The problem is that this seems to work only for the non-single header version of Catch2.

Using single header version of Catch2, the two base classes for reporters (
*Catch::StreamingReporterBase* and *Catch::CumulativeReporterBase*) are not accessible.

They are not accessible because they are in a part of the header that is not included by the precompiler (by the way, I don't understand how default reporters work as they too are in not-included segments of the header).

Does someone know **how to create custom reporters with single-header version of Catch2**?

**EDIT** : I am using version 2 of Catch. The reporter base definitions are in a block disabled by a #ifdef **OBJC** block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of the library you are using. Versions 2.x were based on the single header *catch.hpp* and had numerous additional [macros](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/v2.x/docs/configuration.md#reporter--listener-interfaces) to configure what is included from that header. In particular, you would need

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_EXTERNAL_INTERFACES
#include "catch.hpp"
```

to access the reporter definitions.

With versions 3.x, this has changed and there are two options:

- Adopt the new library architecture, meaning you link your targets against Catch2 and include the appropriate reporter header, e.g.

  ```
  #include <catch2/reporters/catch_reporter_streaming_base.hpp>
  ```
- Use the *catch_amalgamated.hpp/cpp* files to compile the library as a single translation unit. Additional configuration should no longer be needed to make the reporter classes available.

See also [this document](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/migrate-v2-to-v3.md) for more information on migrating to version 3.